# Google Team Drive Create Folders not showing up

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I've been trying to create sub-folders in a Team Drive using the Python REST API via a service account and haven't been able to get it to work "successfully"

```
def create_folder(service, folder_name):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': folder_name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'supportTeamDrives': True,
        'parents': [{'id':'Parent Folder ID Here'}]
    }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                  fields='id').execute()
    print 'Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id')
    return file.get('id')
```

Now, the code runs and I get a folder ID back. However, when I go into my own personal account that's a member of the team drive I don't see the folder at all and when I take the ID directly and paste it into the browser it says that I need to request access. I think the folders are being created but having their permissions restricted somehow. However, reading the documentation here,

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing

Regarding the ownership transfer in and out of Team Drives, I had assumed that anything created in a Team Drive would have it's permission set to be available to all in the Team Drive. What am I missing?